# QWidget minimum visible width

Tags: c++, qt

In this **example** the **Pink QWidget** has her `Horizontal` and `Vertical` policy set to `Ignored` so it can be completely 'resized' to the minimum size, which is `0`.

How I can set a 'minimum *visible* width' to the `PushButton` became visible?

I created this gif to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

As seen in the gif the `PushButton` became visible as soon as her parent becomes visible (default behavior), I would like to make it visible only when there's a *specific* amount of space in the parent.

I wonder if this could be achieved with any kind of CSS similar to:

```
     min-width: 0;
     max-width: 200;
     /* min-visible-width: 100; */ <- example
```

**or** by editing the button/parent properties in the **Qt Designer**, **instead** of subclassing the button and setting it hidden/unhidden according to her size.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you mean by `"I would like to make it visible only when there's a specific amount of space in the parent."`.  Under what conditions should the button become visible/invisible?

Comment: Override parent's `resizeEvent()` or (even better) handle parent's resize event in button's event filter (read about event filters...) and set button's visibility iif the parent's width is greater than button's `minimumWidth()`, `minimumSizeHint().width()` or `sizeHint().width()`. Which one you will you is up to you and your use case and sizing policy of the button. Qt is not a trivial framework but if you know how to use it, it can be very flexible and powerful.